# Application Not Loading Token from LocalStorage After Sign In But Works After Refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jwt, angular12

I have an angular application and for some reason, the localstorage is showing the token from current User as null and therefore, the api return a 401 unauthorized. The issue happens after login and saving the token to localStorage and routes to the proper component to handle the next request. The request at this next page after login is returning 404 because the jwt did not find the token in the localstorage. Once I refresh the page, the api's start working again as if it found the token.

I have tried multiple approaches such as trying to inject localstorage, try async localstorage get, etc but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

my JWT Interceptor is:

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
      let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

      if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
                }
            });
        } 

      return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

The authentication Code is t which I get and save to user is(the use of this function in the component is under this):

```
login(merchantId: string, client_id: string, code: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/cloverApi/authenticate`, {merchantId: merchantId, client_id: client_id, code: code})
      .pipe(map(token => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        this.role = token.role;
        if (token && token.access_token) {
          // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          this.setCookie('clover_access_token_cookie', 'Generic User', 364); //expires in 364 days as token only last 365
          console.log('in clover auth.service login completed. Cookie Stored under username: ' + this.getLoggedInSubject()); //*MES*
          return token;
        }
      }));
  }
```

So I get the clover api token and set it to the current user and send an update request as shown here:

```
this.cloverTokenService.login(this.url_merchant_id, this.url_client_id, this.url_code)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.currentUser.cloverToken = data.access_token;
            this.currentUser.merchantId = this.url_merchant_id;
            this.userService.update(this.currentUser).subscribe((updatedUser:User)=> {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));
                localStorage.setItem('', '');
                this.checkAuthAndRoute();
            },
              error => {
                console.error(error);
              })
          },
          error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

While setting your object in localStorage your token is under `currentUser.cloverToken` then when you retrieve it your trying to read `currentUser.token`

Either do this `this.currentUser.token= data.access_token;` or this `Authorization: Bearer ${currentUser.cloverToken}`

Comment: No, my token is under token, clover token is something different

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can make use of `BehaviorSubject` to pass token around as getting data from localstorage could have caused the issue somehow. You can next to the behavior subject when login succeeds and that can be used by the interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're using `this.currentUser` instead of the `updatedUser` inside the `subscribe` method.

And **you are not setting `this.currentUser.token` anywhere** in the snippets you provided. So, it's going to be `undefined` when you use it in your interceptor unless you are setting it somewhere else.

To confirm this, check your local storage from the browser. For example, in Chrome, it would be under the `Application` tab.

[image]

If `currentUser` appears there but doesn't have the `token` property then it's what I already mentioned.

If `currentUser` appears in the local storage with the `token` property, then you're probably not setting your interceptor correctly. In that case, you may find [this article about interceptors](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-interceptors-a-complete-guide-7294e2317ecf) helpful.

For example, I don't know if you omitted this on purpose but I don't see your interceptor annotated with the `@Injectable()` decorator.

Comment: The token is returned in the currentUser from the backend. so if the currentuser exists, the token does as well.

Comment: @z123 Then I suggest you provide a StackBlitz demo to help you with debugging your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue probably happens because you set the token on the application startup, but never update it upon login.

You would need to "refresh" the value when a login happens by checking again for the localStorage data.

A quick solution would be to calculate the headers every time you call the API

```
function getHeaders() {
return { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')}` }
```

and then call this getHeaders() function on each endpoint